# Piping for loop output prevents local variable modification

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, scripting, pipe

I'm trying to write a simple bash function that takes, as its arguments, a number of files and/or directories. It should:

1. Fully qualify the filenames.
2. Sort them.
3. Remove duplicates.
4. Print all that actually exist.
5. Return the number of non-existent files.

I have a script that almost does what I want, but falls down on the sorting. The return value of the script as it stands is correct, but the output is not (unsorted and duplicates). If I uncomment the `| sort -u` statement as indicated, the output is correct but the return value is always `0`.

N.B. Simpler solutions to solve the problem are welcome but the question is really about why is this occurring in the code I have. That is, why does adding the pipe seemingly stop the script incrementing the variable `r`?

Here's the script:

```
function uniqfile
{
    local r=0 

    for arg in "$@"
    do  
        readlink -e "$arg" || (( ++r ))

    done #| sort -u    ## remove that comment

    return $r
}
```

Comment: Just a small observation. You can reduce `for arg in "$@"` to `for arg`. "If 'in WORDS ...;' is not present, then 'in "$@"' is assumed." - help for

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a well known bash pitfall, due to this *feature*:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).

so that modified variables are local to the subshell, and not visible once back in the parent.

To avoid that, rephrase your code to avoid the pipeline, with a process substitution:

```
 for arg in "$@"
    do  
        readlink -e "$arg" || (( ++r ))

    done > >(sort -u)
```

Comment: Thankyou. That's great. I wonder if you could tell me the name of the `>(..command..)` construct. I *think* I know how it works but feel I should do some further reading.

Comment: @tjm: it is called *process substitution*

Comment: Process substitution in Bash has many forms: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html

Comment: [*Process substitution*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution)  is a form of inter-process communication that allows the input or output of a command to appear as a file. The command is substituted in-line, **where a file name would normally occur**, by the command shell. This allows programs that normally only accept files to directly read from or write to another program.

Answer (score 3):

The `| sort -u` forces the preceding bit (so the whole for loop) to run in a sub-process (bash needs a 'STDOUT' to redirect into the `sort` 'STDIN'.  (Internet seems to think `ksh` and `bash` handle this case slightly differently .. first or last command in the pipe sequence gets put into a subshell?)

This thread goes over a similar problem, and has a neat solution at the end: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=312017

*excerpt*

> ```
>     #!/bin/bash
>     exec 3< <(du | sort -n)  
>
>     n=0
>     while read size dir; do
>       [ $size -gt 1000 ] && ((n++))
>     done <&3
>     exec 3<&-
>
>     echo "Found $n too big files"
> ```